# image isn't shown on mobile browsers

Tags: image, mobile, browser

In my PHP page I have a table where in one of the cells a picture is loaded dynamically:

```
<td class="text-centered">
  <a href="modifica.php?id=<?php echo $objResult["id"];?>">
    <img src="img/update.gif" width="29" height="20" title="modifica">
  </a>
</td>
```

It works perfectly on any pc, but it doesn't show on smartphones. I tried several browsers and the problem persists.
Any ideas?

Comment: How's the image is loaded using PHP?

Comment: I see your point. PHP is not really the issue here.